# Uuse constrained relation while creating column in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-relations

I have a company_balances table in the database with the `amount` and `balance` columns. The `amount` column can have negative and positive values. So I want to make a constrained relation between the `balance` and `amount` columns, where `balance` will show the sum of the column `amount`. I did not find any tutorial in Laravel documentation for this case. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried the code below in my migration file.

```
Schema::create('company_balances', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->float('balance');
    $table->float('amount');
    $table->text('particulars');
    $table->foreignId('vendor_id')->nullable()->constrained()
        ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
});

Schema::table('company_balances', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('balance')->references('id')->on('company_balances');
});
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that constraint is what you are looking for. Looks like you need database trigger or function to calculate that

Comment: Yes, it seems like that. because as far as I understand constrained is something where we link the columns but calculating is not mentioned in anywhere. I just don't want to calculate the company balance each time in the admin panel, it would make all much easier.

Comment: think this is not some Laravel problem, try it in a MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea your algorithm but simply you could do this in the `boot` method of the model (**CompanyBalance**):

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(function ($model) {
        $model->balance += $model->amount;
    }); 
}
```